# Synergy mouse/keyboard freezes on SUSE 11.1

Tags: synergy, suse

I am running Synergy 1.3.1 client on a SUSE 11.1 machine and the server on a Win7 machine.

Every once in a while (~once every few minutes), the client-side mouse and keyboard will freeze for several seconds and then wake back up again.  Sometimes the freeze is long enough that I end up just moving over and using the physical mouse/keyboard (which always work fine).  I've reniced the synergyc process to maximum priority which seems to have helped quite a bit but hasn't eliminated the problem.

I've monitored the processor/network/resource loads and don't see anything suspicious when the freeze occurs.

My previous machine was a SUSE 10.2 machine running the exact same client and I never had any problems.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've had that same thing happen, albeit much less frequently.  I'm fairly certain it had to with network traffic (at least in my case).  The problem has completely gone away since I switched to using a different router.

Comment: I would buy that explanation if it wasn't for the fact that the 10.2 machine on the same network worked without any problems.  I suppose anything is possible...

Comment: I had asked http://superuser.com/q/218029/16133 earlier.  I never did much as far as checking out the possibilities since changing routers (for an unrelated purpose) fixed it, but perhaps his answer could provide some ideas to try if you haven't already done some of those things.  I wish I could help more, but that's all I know.  GL!